# Browser with lowest CPU / memory usage

Tags: web-browser

Could you suggest me browser with lowest CPU / memory usage?

Requirements:

- I need to open many tabs (30-40)
- Close/open tabs over and over again
- Flash/JavaScript not needed
- Images not really needed

What I tried:

- I've tried with Google Chrome It works normally when I start, but after 5 times 30 tabs closed and opened again It became very high memory usage.
- As I know IE, Opera and Firefox Mozilla not so best choice.

Could you suggest me any other browser with really low memory / CPU usage?

Comment: Read this http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9243574/5_lesser_known_browsers_Free_lightweight_and_low_maintenance

Comment: I think chrome is your best bet for a lightweight browser...what you are doing simply requires a lot of memory.

Comment: What features do you need - I'm see tabs and low memory; what else: ie images (as miroxlav said)? How about JavaScript? How about Flash? CSS? etc.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: Do you need to see/read the content of the pages, or is it only about the GET requests?

Comment: [High memory usage alone is not a bad thing.](http://www.howtogeek.com/128130/htg-explains-why-its-good-that-your-computers-ram-is-full/) In theory we could make a browser that uses very little memory and simply cached everything to disk - it would be the slowest browser ever though.

Comment: In case you are looking for benchmarks, see [Web Browser Grand Prix XVI by THG](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/chrome-27-firefox-21-opera-next,3534.html). It is almost a year old, so represents only old versions of browsers, but may still be more or less relevant.

Comment: If you need to open several tabs at once, you may want to try either the Firefox configuration option for deferred loading of tabs Also you may find useful the option "Don't load tabs until selected" (Options → tab "Tabs") if you don't need to load content from all pages directly at start-up. [taken from @user3075942]. Alternatively, perhaps declutter the tabs you have open using  a chrome Extension like OneTab, or a read-it-later service like Pocket. Knowing your use case for this would help. (Also, memory is cheap - in fact one of the cheapest components to upgrade.)

Comment: @congusbongus, You are missing the point. High memory usage is not a bad thing if you have RAM, but when you run out of RAM, thrashing starts and browser will no longer respond properly. Planned storage to disk is better than thrashing.

Comment: @James, Chrome is one of the most memory intensive browsers ever because each tab is like a "standalone browser". Chrome is known for its speed, and that's because its one of the most **heavyweight** RAM-gobbling browsers out there.

Comment: have you tried `elinks`?

Answer (score 10):

I often browse in the console using [w3m](http://www.howtogeek.com/103574/how-to-browse-from-the-linux-terminal-with-w3m/). Being a console app I thought that it would be intimidating, but in fact it is *very* easy to use. Note that w3m supports the two features that you mention: tabs and low memory usage.

For browsing simple websites such as Slashdot I find w3m **even easier to use that Firefox**, but for web applications (such as Stack Overflow) it is useless.

Comment: There is console client for SO.

Answer (score 7):

Why not [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)?

Go to **about:config** page and adjust the following settings:

```
javascript.enabled -> false      # Disable JavaScript
permissions.default.image -> 0   # Disable images by default
plugin.state.flash -> 0          # Never activate Flash
```

Also you may find useful the option "Don't load tabs until selected" (Options → tab "Tabs") if you don't need to load content from *all* pages directly at start-up.

Maybe [Adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) will help also but it depends on your pages. Don't forget that you may also write your personal rules to block loading of unneeded elements.

If you already using Firefox as a normal browser, you will be interested in [creating separate profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) with adjusted settings and [launching them in parallel](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/922363).

Answer (score 4):

There is also a text-only browser [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) (it is not tabbed, so you will have new windows instead of tabs) which is very light on resources. There are also browsers that build on it: [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)) and [links2](http://pupnik.de/links2.html) (with image support) and [elinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks) (with Javascript support but without images).

Answer (score 0):

There are two browsers that I know of that will support your requirements. One is [Diglo](http://www.diglo.com/) and the other is [Blackhawk](http://www.netgate.sk/blackhawk/help/welcome-to-blackhawk-web-browser.html). They are both based off of Chrome but their memory use is very low. I have ran as many as 300+tabs on Diglo.

Comment: I would upvote if I saw with Q/A earlier but today Diglo link seems to be dead. Blackhawk pages don't have any timestamps and the copyright is 2011, so I can't tell it's enough up-to-date to be safe to use in modern web.